# How to install Windows XP on a new ASUS laptop

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have installed Windows XP a thousand times before; so I know everything about it. But when I tried to install it on my new laptop (ASUS V502U) this screen appears:

[image]

I tried "Service Pack 3" and "Service Pack 2 x64" from USB and external DVD drive but the result is the same each time. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error says, and looking for a BIOS update for your laptop, or following the other instructions?

Comment: Not yet. I'm on it

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why are you trying to install Windows XP?  These days, you will encounter a lot of driver-related problems with this scenario.  For starters, Windows XP and Server 2003 don't natively support SATA hard drives, and there are many other components within that laptop that are much newer than that.

Comment: @Run5k I have windows10x64 installed and it's ok. I understand; and there is no reason to use windows xp anymore. The only thing that made me do it is an "AVR programmer"(STK500) which I can not find it's drivers for windows 10 and even 7. you can find a few things if you search for it but none of them worked for me. I have used it on windows xp before and I know that it works there. I tried VMware first but the virtual machine is on my windows 10 and the host must be able to use that device in the first place

Comment: Is that notebook in UEFI mode or legacy BIOS mode?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I looked everywhere and there is no option to select between these two. The only thing I found was "Legacy USB Support" which is "Enabled" by default

Comment: So the STK500 is an external device? Is it USB? Have you tried USB pass through in the VM? I bet you could buy an old laptop on eBay with XP on it for £20. Might be worth looking at that.

Comment: if there's no option then I'd say it's an UEFI-only machine, and won't run XP. Have you tried the F7 to skip ACPI detection yet (as the message suggests)?

Comment: @ِDarren yes it is an external USB device. I had a quick search about pass through and I thought it may be helpful. It is a little bit confusing and I don't know anything about it yet (I will continue reading about it. is there any quick guide?). Since I am in the middle east and I don't have any suitable bank account to pay on ebay, the last option is not available for me

Comment: How about running it in a VM instead?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 OH! thank you. At least now I know that I should stop trying. Yes I tried pressing F7 continually after booting. The same screen appeared again but the message was a little different. It was something like check for newly installed hardware and disk errors (which is not any helpful)

Comment: @Tetsujin as I mentioned in previous comments I have done it before and  it didn't work out

Comment: USB pass-through has no requirement for the host to have any drivers specific to the device installed.

Comment: USB pass-through needs only CPU and motehrboard support (and the corresponding option on the BIOS/setup enabled), and on Linux, some extra boot CLI parameter. I have successfully used it on my qemu virt-manager VMs.

Comment: I am done with that idea since everyone is telling me the same: I can not install Windows XP on this laptop! So I tried using another computer and my problem with using that device is solved. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am almost certain you will not get this to work. There's probably some hardware in the laptop that XP does not have the drivers for - no surprise, hardware has moved on a lot since XP was released. You can load drivers before starting the install (you press one of the function keys) but good luck working out which one you need and getting hold of it.

Comment: Now I am getting disappointed :(

Comment: @mohammad I don't see the need to, there are plenty of better OSs, many of them being free. Trying to install XP on a new laptop is just sad

Comment: @Rahul2001the reason why I wanted to do it is in the comments under the question itself